# Cannot disinstall PostgreSql by Script Bash - Linux - Must not open dialog confirmation

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, ubuntu-18.04

My goal is to uninstall PostgreSql (installed on a Linux host- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) using a bash script file.

I use the following command:

```
apt remove --purge -y postgresql-12 && apt autoremove -y
```

The problem is that, launching it from the terminal, at a certain point it opens a confirmation window (you have to press enter to go on).

So when I put this command in the bash script file, it gets stuck (as I assume it is waiting for confirmation).

I tried also with 'apt-get' instead of 'apt', but nothing changed.

I tried also adding option '-qq' or --assume-yes, but nothing changed.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` environment variable to `noninteractive` as explained in [man 7 debconf](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man7/debconf.7.html):

> **noninteractive**
> This  is  the  anti-frontend.  It  never  interacts  with you at all, and makes the
> default answers be used for all questions. It might mail error  messages  to  root,
> but  that's  it;  otherwise  it  is  completely  silent  and unobtrusive, a perfect
> frontend for automatic installs. If you are using this front-end, and require  non-
> default  answers  to  questions, you will need to preseed the debconf database; see
> the section below on Unattended Package Installation for more details.

Comment: Does it work in Ubuntu 18.04 too?

Comment: @Fausto70: yes. Ubuntu is based on Debian.